# Web components and JS functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

I'm working on a web component and have a trouble hooking up JS function that randomizes colors. What I have achieved so far is different styles for global DOM and shadow DOM `<h3>` element (sentence 1, and sentence 2 repsectively). What I need is the shadow DOM `<h3>` element to be applied random colors from the array that sits in changeColor() function. Any ideas on how I can incorporate the function into the shadow DOM?

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        h3 {
            color: coral;
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Sentence 2 </h3>
`;
class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
};

window.customElements.define('user-card', UserCard);


function changeColor() {
    let num = 0;
    let arr = ['#FFD640;', '#fdff76', '#f0cd59', '#fa9624', '#fa6824', '#a33f11'];
    window.setInterval(function () {
        num = (num + 1) % 4;
        document.querySelector('h3').style.color = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; 
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Web Components Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Sentence 1</h3>
        <user-card>
            <script src="userCard.js"></script>
        </user-card> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] the post and show an example of how you want to use the `changeColor` function? It sounds as if you want `changeColor` as an additional method inside the class body. If you then change the `setTimeout` callback to an arrow function, change `document.querySelector('h3')` to `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h3')`, and, inside the `constructor`, call `this.changeColor();`, is this what you want the code to do?

Comment: What I did so far was adding, `arr=[...]` and `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h3').style.color = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];` right into the constructor, but it didn't give me any automation in terms of colors. I still have to manually reload the page to change the color

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Define the colors in the class as a property. Create a function or a *getter* for retrieving the `h3` element from the Shadow DOM for easy access.

Custom Elements have lifecycles, meaning that it has certain methods that will be called at certain points in time depending on the context. `connectedCallback` will be called when the element is placed inside the main DOM and will ensure that your component is rendered and ready. In there call your `setInterval` logic. Change the `function()` declaration to an arrow function `() =>` to ensure that the `this` keyword points at the component.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        h3 {
            color: coral;
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Sentence 2</h3>
`;

class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  
  colors = ['#FFD640', '#fdff76', '#f0cd59', '#fa9624', '#fa6824', '#a33f11'];

  get heading() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h3');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    window.setInterval(() => {
      this.heading.style.color = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
    }, 1000);
  }
};

window.customElements.define('user-card', UserCard);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Web Components Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Sentence 1</h3>
  <user-card></user-card>
  <script src="userCard.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would shorten it to:

```js
customElements.define('user-card', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = "<style>h3{color:coral}</style><h3>Sentence 2 </h3>";
    let arr = ['#FFD640;', '#fdff76', '#f0cd59', '#fa9624', '#fa6824', '#a33f11'];
    setInterval(() => {
      let newColor = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h3').style.color = newColor;
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```html
<user-card></user-card>
```

- Separate `class` definition only required when you need to use it multiple times
- `super` sets AND returns the 'this' scope, so you can chain on it
- `attachShadow` sets AND returns `this.shadowRoot`, so you can chain on it
- `<templates>` only make sense for more complex HTML, use `.innerHTML` for the easy stuff
- You are storing the ID reference of `setInterval` in `this.changeColor` (required if you want to end the loop) But then you are calling it as a function... see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to pass the `context` for the `querySelector` to `changeColor`, with `document` as the default if no context gets passed. This way `changeColor` becomes more flexible while also retaining backwards compatibility.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        h3 {
            color: coral;
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Sentence 2 </h3>
`;
class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        changeColor(this.shadowRoot);
    }
};

window.customElements.define('user-card', UserCard);


function changeColor(context = document) {
    let num = 0;
    let arr = ['#FFD640;', '#fdff76', '#f0cd59', '#fa9624', '#fa6824', '#a33f11'];
    window.setInterval(function () {
        num = (num + 1) % 4;
        context.querySelector('h3').style.color = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; 
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Web Components Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Sentence 1</h3>
        <user-card>
            <script src="userCard.js"></script>
        </user-card> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your input, guys! It has eventually worked out this way as well:

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        h3 {
            color: coral;
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Sentence 2 </h3>
`;
class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
    
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        let arr = ['#FFD640;', '#fdff76', '#f0cd59', '#fa9624', '#fa6824', '#a33f11'];
        let num = 0;
        this.changeColor = setInterval(() => {
            num = (num + 1) % 4;
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('h3').style.color = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        }, 1000);
        this.changeColor();
        
    }
};

window.customElements.define('user-card', UserCard);
```